# Please help me identify this plant?

Tags: identification

[image]Can anyone help me identify this plant?

Comment: where is this picture taken?

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Comment: Lily of the Valley has venation that looks too fine to be your plant.  Where is it that you live?  This could be a hosta of some sort.  What is the size of the pot in your picture? I have problems with scale, sizes in these photos.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ginger to me but flowering will help in ID'ing. Best guess, Shell Ginger.

Comment: Why do you think so? Can you please add a few words about it so that you would help the OP understand your reasoning? I'm sure they would be happy to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Another ID would be Lily of the Valley. What size pots are the pots in your picture?  Are they 1 gallon or 6" diameter?
[image: Lily of the Valley]
[image: lily of the Valley parts]

Let's try **Hosta; Plantain Lily**?
[image: Hosta, Plantain Lily]

This plant is toxic to cats FYI whatever its ID.  It is a lily of some sort. Lilies are all toxic to cats and dogs. You would think cats know better but some cats are actually attracted to these plants.  Dogs as well.

[image: Hosta "Twilight"]

[image: spring growth of hosta]

Comment: No. leaves of Polygonatum are on steam. On the photo the leaves come from trumk/soil (like palms, but I do not think it is a palm). I think the family (old classification) is correct (but not in Amaryllaceae, or Araceae).

Comment: You mean like pinnate (odd even)?  I think you are so very correct, Giacomo!

Comment: No. They are not pinnate. The leaves are the small one: the flowers are on the stalk, never in the middle of the leaves. BTW there is also a Polygonatum verticillatum. My comment is about the structure of plant (which I still do not have the correct word)

Comment: Structure, do you mean alternate leaved?  Monocot versus dicot?  Parallel venation. What do you know about the flowers?  Color, singular...or in bunches?

Comment: Are these your plants or plants you are considering purchasing?  (They need a bit of fertilizer for sure unless they've recently had fertilizer added).

Comment: It's not a hosta (note that hosta leaves erupt straight from the crown, and the leaves from the photo differentiate from the stem higher up from the ground. The form looks like a Hedychium to me, so maybe a member of the Zingiberaceae family.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is some hybrid of Hosta. Is this a native plant? In the photo it looks very healthy and well watered (or lots of rain)...
I see no signs of rabbit or bug chewing damage, so my guess is it is not growing wild in your back yard. Where are you?

Answer (score 0):

It's ginger of the genus Zingiber, probably Z. officinale, of the Zingiberaceae family.  It's too tall/vertical to be a Hosta and much too large to be Lily of the Valley.  It has tall vertical leaves that have those distinctive ridges. Shell ginger, Alpinia, has leaves that are smoother and the plant is not quite as vertical as Zingiber.

[Wikipedia article on Genus Zingiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zingiber)

[Wikipedia article on Ginger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginger)